# Undefined index error while using $_FILES in PHP and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

I am building file upload using `php` and `jquery`, I made it without a submit button. But everything is working fine but only there is an error it shows me undefined index message.

This is my `html` code:

```
<div id='show'></div>
<form action='demo.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type='file' id='file' name='file'>
</form>
```

This is my `jquery` code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file').change(function(){
        var name = $('#file').attr('name');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'demo.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'file':name},
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#show').html('Loading...');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#show').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false
    });
});
```

This is my `php` code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    // File properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //Extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'png');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
        if($file_error === 0){
            if($file_size <= 2097152){
                $new_file = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $new_file;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                    echo $file_destination;
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

I don't know what is the error and why it's coming.

Comment: When/where does it show an error?

Comment: what is it saying is undefined?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\file\demo.php on line 2

Comment: You are not actually uploading the file.  All you're doing is POSTing the filename.

Comment: I tried `isset($_POST)` and it didn't work

Comment: @DustinScott I just tried your code I didnt get this notice are you sure its not something else showing this error. please show full error

Comment: @meda yeah it will show when I remove the isset($_FILES['file']) the error will appear but even though if it doesn't the picture wont get uploaded

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending data to `$_FILES`, but to `$_POST` actually.

Note the `data` parameter in your `$.ajax()` call: `data: {'file':name}`

Comment: I would recommend you to read more on uploading files using jQuery, or rather, research on jQuery file upload plugins.

Comment: I don't like to use plugins

Comment: Then go with the my suggestion former. :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the jQuery .ajax function, just have the form "submit

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file').change(function(){
        $('form').submit();
        return false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

add following right after

// Disable errors completely

error_reporting(0);

This will help you to remove/ hide all error messages including fatal errors.

Alternatively you can use

// Report simple running errors

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

You can also view [PHP Official](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) documents for alternative options.

Viewing your problem in detail seems more identical like you are trying to upload file via Ajax. Please read a sample about this scenario on [Simple File Upload Using jQuery](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax).